# Entity Framework 4.3 with SQL Server Express migration exception

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first, sql-server-express, entity-framework-4.3

I've set up a (remote) SQL Server Express for my ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework 4.3 project. On my local machine using SQL Compact everything works fine. When I try to connect to the SQL Express server I got the following error on the call `migrator.Update()`:

```
The INSERT permission was denied on the object '__MigrationHistory', database 'MyDataBase', schema 'dbo'.
```

On the server I've done the following:

- Created a user with SQL Server credentials
- Created a database called MyDataBase

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you get your user any permissions on your database? When you create SQL credentials it is actually only login. You than have to create user in the database associated with login and give it permissions for allowed actions on the database.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka I created a new user and new database and now it works, I think I messed up the permissions in the first database. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The DB roles `db_denydatareader`,`db_denydatawriter` must be unchecked for the created user.

Comment: This worked for me as well.

Database -> Security -> Users -> Right cick your user -> properties -> Membership --> uncheck "db_denydatareader" and "db_denydatawriter"

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error too. To fix it I added db_owner to my user's "database role membership", and checked the db_owner check box under "schemas owned by this user" (SSMS 2008).